# How to create WPF Rounded button using class

Tags: c#, wpf

**I want to create Rounded button using class instead of XAML style**

This code work in WinForms app, how i can convert it to WPF code?

```
   public class RoundButton : Button
    {
        protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            GraphicsPath grPath = new GraphicsPath();
            grPath.AddEllipse(0, 0, ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
            this.Region = new System.Drawing.Region(grPath);
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't that kind of defeat the whole purpose of having XAML? If you are using WPF, you should do [something similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601604/wpf-user-control-round-corners-programmatically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a **really** good reason for doing this (like if you really want to custom draw in more complex scenarios like drawing diagrams or similar), you could do something like:

```
public class RoundButton : Button
{
    public RoundButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(RoundButton);
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        double radius = 10;
        double borderThickness = 1; // Could get this value from any of the this.BorderThickness values

        dc.DrawRoundedRectangle(Background, new Pen(BorderBrush, borderThickness), new Rect(0, 0, Width, Height), radius, radius);
    }
}
```

But I really, really recommend going down the XAML route instead in this case. Custom drawing does not make sense here at all.

One obvious issue with the above code, for instance, is that for it to work, you have to disable the default button style or a button will be drawn on top of your drawing.

In this case a style for RoundButton doesn't exist and the control does not define a placeholder for where text or other content should go. If you want this, you are better off defining this style with a control template and could just as well put in the visuals there.